# C# Minimize if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am still a little bit new to C# and I was wondering how i can minimize this code.

This is what I have so far:

```
private void CheckFiles()
{
    if (!File.Exists(ProgramLocation + "\\Server Files\\" + "Bukkit.jar"))
    {
        DownloadBukkitJar();
    }
    else
    {
        Close();
    }
    if (!File.Exists(ProgramLocation + "\\dlls\\" + "HtmlAgilityPack.dll"))
    {
        DownloadHtmlAgilityPackDll();
    }
    else
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

So how could I make this in less code?

Comment: I'm curious why you're concerned with the '_length_' of some code. If you observe the code you should find ways to _improve_ it, thereby often 'reducing' it ...but for a purpose.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment I thought that if you have little code, the program performs better. That probably makes no sense I think.

Comment: More concise code is more readable code. But there is a subtle difference between *concise* and *small*.

Comment: You are calling `Close` twice. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Paul Ruane Yeah, that's what I thought also, but I don't know if it is possible with this sort of codes.  Steven: Yes, it are two seperate functions that both download a different file if it doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Consider using [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991142.aspx) when building paths.

Comment: What has the Close() to do with CheckFiles()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void CheckFile(string path, Action actionIfMissing)
{
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        actionIfMissing();
    }
    else
    {
        Close();
    }
}

public void CheckFiles()
{
    var bukkitPath = Path.Combine(ProgramLocation, String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "Server Files", Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, "Bukkit.jar");
    CheckFile(bukkitPath, DownloadBukkitJar);
    var htmlAgilityPackPath = Path.Combine(ProgramLocation, String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "dlls", Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, "HtmlAgilityPack.dll");
    CheckFile(htmlAgilityPackPath, DownloadHtmlAgilityPackDLL);
}
```

Note - be wary when hard-coding file paths, you should use `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` if you are building up a path, or when combining paths use `Path.Combine`. This will ensure your paths are platform specific which would make your code more portable. I have updated the example to demonstrate how to do this.

Comment: Wow, thanks for this =O This is so much easier to read now :)! +1!

Comment: When you use pathcombine, it seems iffy to hardcode the path separator char in the tail

Comment: @sehe - yeah I was kinda thinking that myself, think I will update it to encorporate using `Path.DirectorySeparator`.

Comment: @James I wouldn't, because it isn't relevant to the question. But so is the use of Path.Combine, which is why I felt triggered to point out the inconsistency

Comment: @sehe - Regardless, the OP has admitted he is *new* to C# so updating the code to show a more reliable way of working with Paths wouldn't do any harm IMO.

Comment: Oh well, now you're calling the methods directly ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the close() or downloadfunctions do but personally i would aim for something like this :

```
private void CheckFiles()
{
    DownloadIfNeeded(ProgramLocation + "\\Server Files\\" + "Bukkit.jar");
    DownloadIfNeeded(ProgramLocation + "\\dlls\\" + "HtmlAgilityPack.dll");
}

private void DownloadIfNeeded(string s)
{
    if (!File.Exists(s))
    {
        DownloadFile(s);
    }
    else
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your taste and coding style guidelines, the following might be a reasonable attempt:

```
private void CheckFiles()
{
    bool bukkit = File.Exists(string.Format("{0}\\Server Files\\Bukkit.jar", ProgramLocation));
    bool htmlap = File.Exists(string.Format("{0}\\dlls\\HtmlAgilityPack.dll", ProgramLocation));

    if (!bukkit)           DownloadBukkitJar();
    if (!htmlap)           DownloadHtmlAgilityPackDll();
    if (bukkit || htmlap)  Close();
}
```

**Notes**

- I assumed that calling `Close` twice was really not meaningful
- Look at the use of String.Format (an example of code clarity *before* performance)

Comment: Close() should probably be called after downloading as you don't know if there might be side-effects to it.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand you're trying to consolidate the two calls to Close() in a single block, here's a way to do so, **assuming that it does not matter how many times Close() is called**

```
bool bukkitExists=File.Exists(ProgramLocation + "\\Server Files\\" + "Bukkit.jar");
bool htmlAgilitPackExists=File.Exists(ProgramLocation + "\\dlls\\" + "HtmlAgilityPack.dll");
if(bukkitExists||htmlAgilitPackExists){Close();}
else{
if (!htmlAgilitPackExists){DownloadHtmlAgilityPackDll();}
if(!bukkitExists){DownloadBukkitJar();}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void CheckFiles()
{
    bool bukkitExists = File.Exists(ProgramLocation + "\\Server Files\\" + "Bukkit.jar");
    if (!bukkitExists)
    {
        DownloadBukkitJar();
    }
    bool agilityExists = File.Exists(ProgramLocation + "\\dlls\\" + "HtmlAgilityPack.dll");
    if (!agilityExists)
    {
        DownloadHtmlAgilityPackDll();
    }

    if (bukkitExists || agilityExists)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

Are you closing a Form?  Did you really want to close it twice?

Answer (score 0):

Some things:
- Concatenate paths using Path.Combine ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx )
- Use the @ sign in front of paths, regex patterns, ... so you don't have to escape 'special characters' ( http://en.csharp-online.net/CSharp_FAQ%3A_What_does_at_sign_identifier_mean )
- Curly brackets { and } are not needed if only one line follows the preceding statement (though some people see this as bad code!)

More tips depending on the context:
- Depending on the function of the Close method, it might be possible to always call it, so you only have two if statements without the else statements and just call Close() at the end of the CheckFiles() method.
- When concatenating strings (if not paths), always use the String.Format method instead of the '+' sign ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx )

In your example:

```
private void CheckFiles()
{
    if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(ProgramLocation, @"Server Files\Bukkit.jar")))
        DownloadBukkitJar();
    else
        Close();

    if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(ProgramLocation, @"dlls\HtmlAgilityPack.dll")))
        DownloadHtmlAgilityPackDll();
    else
        Close();
}
```